# Can you explaing now this works. Python Numpy.arrays working with regular lists

Tags: python, numpy, analysis, data-science

```
positions = ['GK', 'M', 'A', 'D', ...]
heights = [191, 184, 185, 180, ...]
```

Each element in the lists corresponds to a player. The first list, positions, contains strings representing each player's position. The possible positions are: `'GK'` (goalkeeper), `'M'` (midfield), `'A'` (attack) and `'D'` (defense). The second list, `heights`, contains integers representing the height of the player in cm.

1) First I Convert positions and heights to numpy arrays:

```
np_heights = np.array(heights)
np_positions = np.array(positions)
```

Then I find out the Heights of the goalkeepers: gk_heights

```
gk_heights = np_heights[np_positions =='GK']
```

This code works fine and does what it should do.

Now the question.

isn't `np_heights` and `np_positions` two separate lists. how does this line :

```
gk_heights = np_heights[np_positions =='GK']
```

know that a certain index in np_positions is associated to a certain index in `np_heights`?

This is the last question from Data Camp online course:
URL:
https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/intro-to-python-for-data-science/chapter-4-numpy?ex=16

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is tied to what the expression `np_positions=='GK'` means. You should try running only this line to see what the output is. Essentially, the output of this line is a boolean array of the same shape as `np_positions` and elements of the boolean array are `True` where the conditional is satisfied and `False` where the conditional is not satisfied. So, you should get an array back like `np_positions=='GK' = array([True,False,False,False...])`. And then when you use this array as an index slice into `np_heights`, the expression `np_heights[np_positions=='GK']` tells you to "pick out the values of np_heights where the inside array, `np_positions=='GK'`, is `True`. And so, it will pick out the first element of `np_heights`. Hopefully this explanation made sense.

What should be learned from this explanation is that your two arrays **better** be in the same **order**. The two arrays don't communicate to each other on which player gets put in which index. The expression `np_heights[np_positions=='GK']` says in human words: "where in `np_positions` is(are) the goal keeper(s)? Oh it's in index 0 (or others?) - return the index 0 value of `np_height`.

Thus, if goal keeper is the first element of one array, it better be the first element of the second array (and so on and so forth) in order for this expression to work out right.

Comment: enumaris! It is as I thought. the two arrays are not connected. and they better be in the same order otherwise the whole thing will be out of wack. Thanks for your detailed explanation I now am confided that I finished the first course successfully. !

Comment: Impecccable, Thanks @enumaris for the detailed explanation. It helped a lot to understand!